# Avoid restarting macbook pro with bootcamp

Tags: windows, bootcamp

Is there a way to use bootcamp to switch between Windows and OSX without restarting the laptop. I don't really want to buy any virtual software like VMWare or Parallels.

Comment: If you want a laugh, see [this hint](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090331224435492) by MacWorld in 2009!

Comment: lol quite a clever article didnt relise it until i read it second time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You can't run two operating systems at the same time without any extra software.

With that said, Parallels Desktop does exactly what you want to achieve, it runs the OS in a virtual mode, the only downside being it's shareware, therefore pricy. Using a third party software is however the only way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Had a feeling you might say that thanks for answer. do u recommend parrels 8 or vmware

Comment: Personally, I prefer Parallels, but I haven't throughoutly tested VMWare, so someone else might have a better recommendation there :)

Comment: There's also the free VirtualBox software, give it a try and see if it meets your needs before shelling out for one of the others - it depends a lot on what you need Windows for. https://www.virtualbox.org